# Analysis of a complex sample with replicate weights: error when using survey package

Tags: survey, jackknife

I have a data base from a stratified multi-stage survey. Due to confidentiality reasons, they do not gave me the strata neither the psu, ssu… variables. Instead they gave me the:

- “Final weights” which sum is approximately equal to N. these weights include the deff, a non response weight and they are also calibrated for sex and strata. (I will call these weights “FinalW”)
- “Replicate weights” for Jacknife method (I will cal this file “repw”)
- “Coeficientes” for Jacknife method (I will cal this file “jkcoef”)
- “Normalized weights” with mean equal to 1 (I don’t know why it is equal to 1). According to the available information, these weights are the “Final weights” times the ratio between sample size and population size by strata and sex. (I will cal these weights “NormW”)

To define the design I used the svrepdesign:
design_name<-svrepdesign(data=name_data_base,repweights= repw, weights=~FinalW, type="JKn",rscales=jkcoef,scale=1,combined.weights=F)

I tried to compute several t-test for independente samples using svyttest and svy.glm.
 Example: svyttest(NumericVariable~FactorVariable, design_name)
          summary(svyglm(NumericVariable~FactorVariable, design=design_name))
With both instructions I get the error:
“Error in crossprod(x, y):   requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments”

Actualy I get this error also with svychisq, svyglm,…

Can anybody tell me what I’m doing wrong? Do these functions work with replicate weights? Or should I use the usual instructions (outsider survey package) with normalized weights? What are the consequences of such a procedure or it is equivalent to use the functions of survey package?

I will be very grateful if somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Please, apologize my English but I’m not native in English.

Comment: Can you report: summary(name_data_base\$NumericVariable) and summary(name_data_base\$FinalW)?? I just want to make sure everything looks like it is class numeric instead of a factor or something weird.

Comment: your english is fine, it's [your example that needs work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?lq=1).  ;)  could you please use `dput` and create some objects for us?  if you have confidentiality concerns, overwrite the real data with fake data.